# dataform.js:49 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, forms, ecmascript-6, fetch, client

I don't know why but my console told me that I have an error in my sendData function! However I test my code multiple time and it works with others people. Moreover my code worked perfectly and it's stopped working. So i hope someone can help me with this! I don't know where is the mistake!

```
const form = document.querySelector("#form");
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const nom = document.querySelector("#Nom").value; //LastName
const prenom = document.querySelector("#prenom").value; //FirstName
const email = document.querySelector("#email").value; //Email
const textarea = document.querySelector("#subject").value;



//Validations
if (!nom || nom.length < 2 || nom.length >= 50) {
    return;
} else if (!prenom || prenom.length < 2 || prenom.length >= 50) {
    return;
} else if (!email || email.length < 3 || email.length >= 50) {
    return;
} else if (!textarea || textarea.length < 5 || textarea.length >= 500) {
    return;
} else {
    


    //Data
    const data = {
        nom: nom,
        prenom: prenom,
        email: email,
        textarea: textarea,
    };


    //fetching data
    async function sendData() {
        const result = await fetch("/mail", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })

        const clearForm = () => {
            document.querySelector("#email").value = "";
            document.querySelector("#subject").value = "";
            document.querySelector("#Nom").value = "";
            document.querySelector("#prenom").value = "";
        }
        clearForm();


    }
    sendData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in fact I saw the issue yesterday night! It was a server problem cause I didn't respond with res.end() or (res.send() or res.json()..whatever). So thank you!LOL